# Is there any data tidying tool for python/pandas similar to R tidyr tool?

Tags: r, python, dataset, data-cleaning, pandas

I'm working on a Kaggle challenge where some variables are represented by rows instead of columns (Telstra Network Disruption). I am currently searching for the equivalent of `gather()`, `separate()` and `spread()`, which can be found in R `tidyr` tool.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10109

Answer (score 8):

I'd start with the `melt()` function in pandas.  I wrote an article about it:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Tidy_Data_In_Python?lang=en

Answer (score 4):

R's `gather()` essentially goes from wide to long. So,

1. check [pandas page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) for how to use `pandas.wide_to_long()`,
2. check [this blog](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/08/28/tidyr-and-pandas-gather-and-melt/) for a discussion on getting an elegant `gather`-like function in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to syntactically mimic the tidyr package in python in a package called tidypython. I made it compatible with the dplython package, which includes usage of the >> operator for chaining commands.

It hasn't been fully tested, but should work pretty well:

https://github.com/durrantmm/tidypython

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of `tidyr` in python:

https://github.com/pwwang/datar

Disclaimer: I am the author.